# What caused a fall in atmospheric oxygen about 1.9 billion years ago?

Tags: atmosphere, earth-history, precambrian

Using chromium isotopes geochemistry, Frei et al. 2009, describe in the article [Fluctuations in Precambrian atmospheric oxygenation recorded by chromium isotopes](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v461/n7261/abs/nature08266.html) that after the Great Oxidation Event (2.2-2.45 billion years ago), there was a precipitous decline in atmospheric oxygen at about 1.88 billion years ago, to have "all but disappeared" as described by Lyons and Reinhard 2009 in the article [Early Earth: Oxygen for heavy-metal fans](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v461/n7261/full/461179a.html#B2).

**What evidence is there for a the drop in atmospheric oxygen approximately 1.9 billion years ago?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer might lie in aerobic respiration. This is of course only one of the many possible explanations but mitochondria (and therefore $\ce{O2}$-breathing eukaryotes) are thought to have evolved circa 2.3 to 1.8 Ga (see for instance **[Hedges et al., 2001](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2148-1-4.pdf); [2004](http://www.hedgeslab.org/pubs/156.pdf); [2006](http://www.hedgeslab.org/pubs/182.pdf)**). This loose age bracket however is based primarily on molecular data with very few fossil evidence (as I mentioned in an [earlier answer of mine](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/106/87), the Proterozoic fossil record of eukaryotes is almost inexistant).
An earlier apparition of aerobic respiration is unlikely (e. g. **[Knoll & Holland, 1995](https://books.google.de/books?id=C-siB8GDLGwC&lpg=PA21&ots=ryvu9rVuV4&dq=mitochondria%20evolution%20proterozoic&lr&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q&f=false)**) as a certain level of $p_{\ce{O2}}$ needed to be reached for this metabolism to be possible.
If aerobic eukaryotes expanded rapidly they might have constituted a strong enough sink of oxygen, which could be responsible for the drop observed by **[Frei et al., 2009](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature08266)**.